# How to authenticate user in spring using AuthenticationManagerBuilder and userDetailsService based on credentials retrived from user entity

Tags: java, spring

i am a newbie to spring 
was not able to implement login to the application, actually could not figure out where its wrong.
followed a youtube video to do all this.
Help would be very much appreciated.
When i try to log in the application wont allow to log in.
console logs shows querys are being executed but cant log into the system.
also the password are saved in plain ASCII.

WebSecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = CustomUserDetailsService.class)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private AccessDeniedHandler accessDeniedHandler;

@Autowired 
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
} 


// roles admin allow to access /actuator/**
// roles user allow to access /Application/**
// custom 403 access denied handler

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // some antMatchers permit all
}
}
```

customUserDetailsService class

```
@Service("customUserDetailsService")
public class CustomUserDetailsService  implements UserDetailsService{

private final UserRepo userRepo;

@Autowired
public CustomUserDetailsService(UserRepo userRepo) {
    this.userRepo = userRepo;
}

@Override
// userId is reffered as username
public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user=userRepo.findByUsername(userName);
    if(null == user){
        System.out.println("\n\n\n No user present with username: "+userName);
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException("No user present with username: "+userName);
    }else{  

        CustomUserDetails c =new CustomUserDetails(user);
        //System.out.println(c.getAuthorities());
        return c;
    }
}


}
```

CustomUserDetails class

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public CustomUserDetails(User user){
    super(user);

}

@Override
public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

    Collection<UserRole> roles = super.getUserRole();
    List<String> userRoles= new ArrayList<String>();

    for(UserRole r : roles) {
        userRoles.add(r.getRole().toString());
    }

    String strRoles=StringUtils.collectionToCommaDelimitedString(userRoles);
    return AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(strRoles);
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return super.isAccountNonExpired();
}

@Override
public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return super.isAccountNonLocked();
}

@Override
public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return super.isCredentialsNonExpired();
}

@Override
public boolean isEnabled() {
    return super.isEnabled();
}

@Override
public String getUsername() {
    return super.getUsername();
}

@Override
public String getPassword() {
    return super.getPassword();
}

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ***When i try to log in the application wont allow to log in***? Does your app throw any error or *what do you expect it to return and what does it return in reality*?

Comment: If i do with in memory authentication like auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser(&quot;ram&quot;).password(&quot;ram123&quot;).roles(&quot;ADMIN&quot;) application works fine. I mean i can sucessfully log into. But with userDetailsService i cant even with correct credentials.

Comment: Have you got a `AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter`? Which define `ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer`, `AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer` and `AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer`?

Comment: @PraveenM i dont have. Can you suggest a way to implement?

Comment: Sorry, ignore my last comment as its more towards [OAuth2 Security Configuration](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs). But I just realized that you don't have Database implementation and `UserDetailService` is used with Databases; That's why you can login with simple method but not with `UserDetailService`. http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-with-a-database. Otherwise, you're going to need [InMemoryUserDetailsManager](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.0.0.M5/reference/htmlsingle/#hello-web-security-java-configuration)

Comment: @PraveenM i have fixed my issue. At `CustomUserDetails` i have a object of user which is initialised by constructer. The login is working fine. `public CustomUserDetails(User user){
    super(user);
}` replaced with `public CustomUserDetails(User user){
   this.user=user;
}`